# directory usr/share/codium is not found

Tags: linux, linux-mint, snapcraft

I want to install background extension from codium and it need to run, sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/share/codium  but I can't found /usr/share/codium. Previously I install codium from snap. Any sugestion where is the snap put the directory ?

I use linux mint tricia mate edition

Answer (score 1):

I change my linux distro to manjaro and found the directory on

```
/usr/share/vscodium-bin/
```

I use aur not snap for package manager

Answer (score 0):

Try searching at this location /var/lib/snapd/snaps

Comment: Its not working, I want to install background extension from codium and it need to run,
sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/share/codium . I already trying running sudo chown -R $(whoami) /var/lib/snapd/snaps/codium_19.snap but not working